# "Only a few minutes separate me from..." A common sentence-structure

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I want to rephrase a sentence so it fits the common sentence-structure (I assume it is common), and that's exactly the problem, it seems that I can't recall what that structure is, precisely.

The sentence:

> Only a few minutes separate me from knowing the truth.

Or

> What separates me from knowing the truth is just a few minutes.

How can it be rephrased so it expresses its meaning **completely** and **greatly**? (No harm if you help me in expressing it more **dramatically** too.)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the original version.

Comment: _I'll know the truth in a few minutes_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

> There's only a few minutes **between** me and knowing the truth.